# Store & retrieving session after login Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session

My problem is I want to store session with year information after login, here is my login form
[image]

I've run `php artisan make:auth` then modified LoginController and overrride some functions

```
protected $redirectTo = '/';
protected $year = 2017;

private function setYear($year)
{
    $this->year = $year;
}

private function getYear()
{
    return $this->year;
}

private function setPath()
{
    $this->redirectTo = route('dashboard', ['tahun' => $this->getYear()]);
}

private function getPath()
{
    return $this->redirectTo;
}


protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->username() => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
        'year' => 'required|string'
    ]);
}

protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    $this->setYear($request->input('year'));
    $this->setPath();
    $this->setSession();

    return redirect()->intended($this->getPath());
}

protected function setSession()
{
    session(['year' => $this->getYear()]);
}
```

The login is running well, but I can't get year information from another controller. When I write `dd(session('year'))` it return `null`

Comment: SOLVED! My code is ok, but my mistake is I call the session from the constructor, so it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

```
// Via a request instance...
$request->session()->put('key', 'value');

// Via the global helper...
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

You aren't actually setting anything in the session. You've assigned a value to the property `$year` but that will be lost at the end of the request.

Everything you need to know: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#storing-data

Comment: I've set the session in `setSession` function, please take a look

Comment: How long is your session lifetime set in `config/session.php`?

Comment: Call `save()` before you redirect: `request->session()->save()`

Comment: SOLVED! My mistake is I call the session from the constructor, so it didn't work.