# How to overridden laravel default login function

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

How can I override laravel default login function? Laravel Auth by default uses the `users` table and `User` model for login and authentication. 
But I want to use `API` *(which is in `GCI` and written in python)* for login and authentication keeping everything else same as it is, such as checking if user is logged in from the blade like this `@if(Auth::check) <<Do something>> @endif`and so on.

Is it possible to do so? If so how can I do the same?

I have tried to google it out but I did not any other good article.
I also tried to look over stack overflow, I found some relevant post but those solutions don't fit my problem. Here are some:-

1. [Store & retrieving session after login Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48414268/store-retrieving-session-after-login-laravel)
2. [Laravel 5 Override Login Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483643/laravel-5-override-login-function)
3. [How to do auth without database in Laravel 5.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363521/how-to-do-auth-without-database-in-laravel-5-6)

If this is not possible then how should I approach this problem? 
Thank you for your any response.

Comment: Could you explain the python part a little bit better? How would you like to check if a user is logged in?

Comment: Hi, i do not know what there in the python code. i have only the end point.
Which accept `email address` and `password` and in response it send a json string that contain `token,user info and status` etc